# How to properly automate xml to xls

Tags: ruby, xml, excel, converters, libxml2

I am getting a lot of xml files recently, that i want to analyse in excel. In stead of using the xml conversion standard in (newer versions of) excel, I want to use a Ruby code that does it for a number of files automatically.

I am not very familiar, however, with rexml. After half a days work I got the code to convert just one(!) xml node. This is how it looks:

```
require 'rexml/document'

Dir.glob("FILES/archive/*.xml") do |eksemel|
    puts "converting #{eksemel}"
    filename = (/\d+/.match(eksemel)).to_s 

    xml_file = File.open("#{eksemel}", "r")
    csv_file = File.new("#{filename}.csv", "w")
    xml = REXML::Document.new( xml_file  )

    counter = 0
    xml.elements.each("RESULTS") do |e|
        e.elements.each("component") do |f|
            f.elements.each("paragraph") do |g|
            counter = counter + 1

            csv_file.puts g.text
            end
            end
    end
end
```

Is there a way to a) instead of define the names of the elements and the number let ruby do it automatically and b) save all of these as separate columns in a csv file?

Comment: Why aren't you using the [`CSV`](http://apidock.com/ruby/CSV) library to write CSV files?

Comment: You can have a look at the xmlsimple gem http://xml-simple.rubyforge.org/

Comment: this might help you, get xml elements into hash - https://gist.github.com/amolpujari/5966431

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear what you are using `counter` for. It would also help if you clarified what kind of structure the XML file has (for instance, are there many `<paragraph>` elements within each `<component>` element?). But, here is a cleaner way to write what I think you shooting for:

```
require 'rexml/document'
require 'csv'

Dir.glob('FILES/archive/*.xml') do |eksemel|
    puts "converting #{eksemel}"

    # I assume you are creating a .csv file with the same name as your .xml file
    xml_file = File.new(eksemel)
    csv_file = CSV.open(eksemel.sub(/\.xml$/, '.csv'), 'w')
    xml = REXML::Document.new(xml_file)

    counter = xml.elements.to_a('RESULTS//component//paragraph').length

    xml.elements.each('RESULTS//component') do |component|
        csv_file << component.elements.to_a('paragraph')
    end

    [xml_file, csv_file].each {|f| f.close}
end
```